# Broker is reachable but Kafka can't connect

Tags: apache-kafka, conduktor

I have installed Kafka cluster on Ubuntu 16.04, all the Kafka ports are publicly accessible and I can telnet those ports from outside of the network. I am trying to access the Kafka cluster from Conduktor tool but I keep getting the following error.

`The Broker [IP:Port] is reachable but Kafka can't connect. Ensure you have access to the advertised listeners of the cluster and the proper authorizations.`

Below are my config settings for bootstrap.servers:

For consumer.properties, producer.properties & connect-standalone.properties
`bootstrap.servers=0.0.0.0:9092`
#Tried with localhost as well

For server.properties:
`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.10:9092`  #Private IP

I have tried with both Public & Private IPs but gets the same error from Conduktor.

Comment: If you want to connect to a public IP, then you need to advertise one... 10.0.0.10 is not a public IP. Otherwise, 0.0.0.0 is not a routable address, and localhost isn't correct either if Kafka is running on a different machine. You need to give conduktor that public ip you'd advertise from Kafka

Comment: Thanks for the response @OneCricketeer

I've added the public IP in advertised.listeners and accessing the Kafka cluster using the same public IP from conducktor but still I get the same error.

```advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://125.209.82.XX:9092```

Error from conducktor

```The Broker [125.209.82.XX:9092] is reachable but Kafka can't connect. Ensure you have access to the advertised listeners of the cluster and the proper authorizations.```

Comment: Assuming you have `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`, then that should be fine

Comment: listeners is set to ```listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092``` but still I get the same error from conducktor  "Broker is reachable but Kafka can't connect"

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't Conduktor itself? That message is not useful. Try using kcat or other Kafka CLI tools to debug further.

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Thanks for the advice, I've tried Kafkacat command line utility, it gets connected and then it gives following error, is there any way to fix this?

````% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Timed out``

Comment: More logs


%7|1652122847.874|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap]: 125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> CONNECT
%7|1652122848.045|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap]: 125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#125.209.82.XX:9092
%7|1652122848.045|CONNECTED|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap]: 125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1652122848.214|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap]: 125.209.82.XX:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> UP

Comment: Don't use a producer. Just use `kcat -L -b 125.209.82.XX:9092`. Also verify that `nc  -vz 125.209.82.XX 9092` can connect